# Calling base class clone implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, clone

Trying to implement clone pattern, but stuck with the function invoking order:

I have a **Base** class with a vector of polymorphic classes (Script).

**Base** class's implements a clone function, which essentially makes a copy of itself with all its members (mScripts vector).

**Derived** class's also implements its own version of clone function, and take care of its members cloning. Which is only an integer at this moment.

**The question:** How should I invoke **Base** class' clone function, in **Derived** class' clone function, so each class takes care of the cloning of its own members?

As an ugly workaround, right now, all my Derived classes' clone function manually do the mScripts vector cloning basically repeating the same code.

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual std::unqique_ptr<Base> clone()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Base> clonedInstance = std::make_unique<Base>();

        //clone the underlying vector
        for(int i = 0; i < mScripts.size(); ++i)
        {
            clonedInstance->mScripts.push_back(std::move(mScripts[i]->clone()));
        }

        return std::move(clonedInstance);
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ScriptBase>>    mScripts;   //polymorphic array
};



class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    Derived(const int x) : Base(), mX(x)
    {
    }

    std::unqique_ptr<Base> clone()
    {
        //calling base::clone() here?

        return std::unique_ptr<Base> clonedInstance = std::make_unique<Derived>(mX);
    }

private:

    int mX;

};
```

Comment: Implement copy constructor correctly, then each clone function is simply `return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement copy constructor correctly, then each clone function is simply `return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);`

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& rhs) // default is not fine here
    {
        for (const auto& script : rhs.mScripts)
        {
            mScripts.push_back(script->clone());
        }
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Base>(*this);
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ScriptBase>> mScripts;   //polymorphic array
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int x) : Base(), mX(x) {}
    Derived(const Derived&) = default; // Default is fine here

    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);
    }

private:
    int mX;
};
```

Comment: i totally missed the copy constructor role here, i see now , thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

For instance, define an additional constructor that accepts a `Base` as argument. Make it `private` if you don't want to expose it:

```
struct Base {
     Base(Base &&) = default;
};

class Derived: public Base {
    Derived(Base &&b, int x): Base(std::move(b)), mX(x) {}
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const {
        auto retBase{Base::clone()};
        return std::make_unique<Derived>(std::move(*retBase), mX);
    }
};
```

(your `Base` is not trivially copyable anyway.)

Another way is to add templated cloning, when all the `Base` cloning is done inside a CRTP-like templated function with possible further tweaks to the returned value:

```
class Base {
protected:
    template<typename Concrete> std::unique_ptr<Base> recreate() const {
         std::unique_ptr<Base> retVal{std::make_unique<Concrete>()};
         // ???????
         return retVal;
    };
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const { return recreate<Base>(); }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const {
        auto retVal{recreate<Derived>()};
        retVal->mX = mX;
        return retVal;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the multiple choices, i guess i will go with the more trivial copy constructor approach